# Please help in escaping this SQL string to C# string

Tags: c#

```
'<ad name="'+ am.name+ '" tag="C" cityid="'+cast(am.city_id as varchar) +'" 
 stateid="'+convert(varchar(11),cast(cm.state_id as varchar)) +'" capital="N"> 
 </ad>' as chkdata
```

I have above  statement in SQL query.

I want to add this to C# string

Unsucessful attempt

```
string sqlqry = "\'<ad name=""\'+ am.name_id + \'"" tag=""C"" 
cityid=""\'+cast(am.city_id as varchar) +\'"" 
stateid=""\'+convert(varchar(11),cast(cm.state_id as varchar)) +\'"" capital=""N"">
</ad>\' as chkdata ,";
```

Later I am doing this . I am building a query in string.

```
sqlcountcmd = new SqlCommand(finalsqlqry, sqlconn);
```

+1 to all guaranteed

Comment: Just remove the `@` as the string isn't verbatim...

Comment: tried it but didn't work

Comment: it would be far preferable to simply `select` the columns you want, and let your application layer worry about xml

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187339(v=sql.100).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

presumably that *entire thing* is to be treated as sql - not a composite of sql and C#. Thus if we use a verbatim literal we only need to worry about the `"`s:

```
string s = @"'<ad name=""'+ am.name+ '"" tag=""C"" cityid=""'+cast(am.city_id as varchar) +'"" 
stateid=""'+convert(varchar(11),cast(cm.state_id as varchar)) +'"" capital=""N""> 
</ad>' as chkdata ,";
```

However! I **strongly** suggest not doing this. You should just return the *columns* from SQL, and let your app tier worry about xml/html etc.

Comment: Yes entire thing is to be treated as sql - not a composite of sql and C#

Answer (score 1):

So, if I've understood correctly, you'll only need to escape the double quotes `"` and not single quotes `'`

```
string sqlqry = "'<ad name=\"'+ am.name_id + '\" tag=\"C\" " +
"sectordetailid=\"'+cast(am.sector_detail_id as varchar) +'\" " +
"stateid=\"'+convert(varchar(11),cast(cm.state_id as varchar)) +'\" capital=\"N\">" +
"</ad>' as chkdata";
```

You can use the verbatim character `@` I'm sure, but I've not got Visual Studio in front of me to check.